# wordpress new WP_Query between not working

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I make it filter between the two integers?

This is my PHP

```
$filter = array(
    'post_type'     => 'request',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'first_posting_date',
        'value' => array('20170826','20170829'), //already tried to remove the qoutes on numbers
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    );
    $posts = new WP_Query($filter);
    print_r($posts);
```

The results of `print_r` it displaying the outside of the filtered of two integers. Where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple meta values can be compared with BETWEEN with an array value:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'first_posting_date',
        'value' => array('20170826','20170829'),
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
    ),
   ),
```

You can see this in Codex

Comment: use
'value' => array(20170826,20170829),
without quotes

Comment: I was just missing `'type'    => 'numeric',`

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
//Date
$start = '2017-08-26';
$end = '2017-08-29';
$filter = array(
    'post_type' => 'request',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'first_posting_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'first_posting_date',
            'value' => array($start, $end),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
);

// Make the query
$posts = new WP_Query($filter);
print_r($posts);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is `relation` and put the array of `meta_query` to other array

so it would be like this

```
$filter = array(
    'post_type'     => 'request',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
         "relation" => "AND",
         array(
            'key' => 'first_posting_date',
            'value' => array('20170826','20170829'),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
          )
       )
    );
    $posts = new WP_Query($filter);
    print_r($posts);
```